# MySQL, trigger that generates primary key before insert a row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a primary key based on current date and time,

Here's my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cuenta
BEFORE UPDATE ON cuenta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cuenta VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.NoCuenta = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%000%d%m%y%h%i%s');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My table cuenta:

```
NoCuenta, varchar(15), NOT NULL.
TipoCuenta, varchar(7),
saldo, float
IDCliente, int(8).
```

Then I try to insert:

```
insert into banco.cuenta(TipoCuenta, saldo, IDCliente)
    VALUES('Debito','12500.5','1');
```

The result:
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1364 Field 'NoCuenta' doesn't have a default value
But when I type select*from cuenta... NoCuenta field is empty.

And then when I try to insert a new row, it shows this:
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you inserting into the table in the trigger?  Just try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER cuenta
BEFORE UPDATE ON cuenta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.NoCuenta = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%000%d%m%y%h%i%s');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found the error.

it is:

BEFORE INSERT ON cuenta, not BEFORE UPDATE ON cuenta.